# How to check for windows that if Automatic date time setting is enabled on the windows device or not?

Tags: c#

I need to read the value of Date Time setting of windows 10 device to verify if it is enabled or not

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _too broad_ and might be off-topic for SO.  Do you have any code to show?  If so post it and maybe we can help. [mvce].  Good luck!

Comment: Maybe [this article about changing time zones](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Changing-time-zones) helps or puts you on the right track

Comment: Are you checking for daylight savings? ntp?

Comment: @IDarkCoder the link is really interesting, but not useful to OP. Looks like OP wants to know if the computer has NTP enabled.

Comment: Not sure if windows calls do allow that, but you can always execute a process and parse the output [How can I check a system's current NTP configuration?](https://superuser.com/questions/425233/how-can-i-check-a-systems-current-ntp-configuration)

Comment: [mcve] I meant to say

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by reading the registry :

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters**

Value : **Type**

Check if it is = *NTP* (Automatic) or *NoSync*